# How to uninstall wine?

Tags: wine, uninstall

I have a question. How to completely remove wine?I tried

```
sudo apt-get purge wine 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get install -f 
rm -r ~/.wine 
rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programms 
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine*
```

But it saying:`Package 'wine' is not installed`, so not removed
What to do?

Comment: The package is not installed so why would you want to uninstall it?

Comment: If it still runs after those attempts to remove it, then it was not installed with the package manager. Do you know how it was installed? Or where it is installed? Then you can take more precise steps to actually remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your wine version:

`wine --version`

After that, put the version after wine in your command.
For example, my version is `wine-2.7`.

`sudo apt-get purge wine-2.7`

Answer (score 0):

The wine binary is not provided by the wine package but either by a wine version specific package or by an architecture specific package depending on your distribution.

This is easy to find and update using aptitude where `l` (limit) allows you to filter your view by string.

Other apt front ends probably have similar functionality.